Netsuite problem rendering picking tickets for specific shipgroups
I am trying to render a picking ticket via the N/render module in suitescript 2.0. We only want to print picking tickets for selected shipgroups. Enable Item Line Shipping has been turned on in the account. I have created a suitelet that displays the sales order lines and provides a checkbox to allow the user to select which ship group they would like to print a picking ticket for. The Netsuite help docs say that the render.pickingTicket function accepts a shipgroup parameter. However, when I pass the shipgroup in to this function, it prints a picking ticket showing all the lines on the sales order and disregards the ship group that I passed in.
If I click on print picking ticket from the sales order screen directly, it prints a picking ticket for each ship group on the order.
The problem, is that we don't want the ship groups that don't have anything left to pick, to print a picking ticket.
How is netsuite generating the picking ticket for each shipgroup, but the render module does not work like that?
I have tried not sending a ship group, and sending a shipgroup from the sales order, both picking tickets looks the same. I have also tried using a negative ship group number to see if that was the issue, and it also showed the same pdf.

Well, I found a workaround in order to make this work. I made a new PDF Template that filters the line items by the ship group that I would like. I had to create a renderer and set fields on the record to pass in the ship group that I would like to print, instead of calling render.pickingTicket.

Same here. It seems like the location and shipgroup parameters don't work properly on those methods. Maybe I'm not using them right, but I can't find good docs on new ways of using them.
